# How to include a rotated text in a fo:region-body

Tags: xsl-fo

In my XSL page master code looks like this ...

```
<fo:simple-page-master fo:master-name="First" fo:page-width="210.82mm" fo:page-height="297.180mm">
            <fo:region-body fo:region-name="first-graphic-region" fo:border-top="6px solid rgb(164,186,207)" fo:border-bottom="6px solid rgb(164,186,207)" fo:margin="100mm 30mm 27mm 15mm"/>
            <fo:region-body fo:region-name="second-graphic-region" fo:background-color="rgb(164,186,207)" fo:border="1px solid rgb(164,186,207)" fo:margin="100mm 15mm 27mm 185mm"/>
            <fo:region-body fo:region-name="first-flow-region" fo:border="none" fo:margin="35mm 15mm 27mm 15mm"/>
            <fo:region-before fo:region-name="xsl-region-before" fo:extent="55mm"/>
            <fo:region-after fo:region-name="xsl-region-after" fo:display-align="after" fo:extent="27mm"/>
            <fo:region-start fo:region-name="xsl-region-start" fo:extent="15mm"/>
            <fo:region-end fo:region-name="xsl-region-end" fo:extent="15mm"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
```

I have a requirement where in i have to include a vertical text region (rotated 90 degrees) inside the region-body
So that this text appears in all my pages. Anyone out there to help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What worked for me was ... I changed the reference orientation of the side region (right-side)

Something like this ...

```
<fo:region-end fo:region-name="xsl-region-end" fo:extent="25mm" fo:reference-orientation="90"/>
```

Now when i include a block inside the side region. I can  get it printed on all the pages as i require.

Too dumb of me not to try this at first :)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [reference-orientation](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/prop_reference-orientation.asp) property. I'm not sure this works on all elements, but it does work on a fo:block.

Comment: Thank you Peter. The orientation property works for the fo:block only when the block is used in static content.